# Dependency Injection and Required Default Constructor

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, automapper

Background: I'm creating a CustomResolver for AutoMapper. That CustomResolver itself needs to use the automapper profile to map a nested model. I'd like to inject the instance of automapper via dependency injection. However, the compiler complains that a parameterless constructor is needed for the custom resolver. Once I create that, then the program seems to default to using the parameterless constructor instead of the one that utilizes dependency injection. In order to have the parameterless constructor work, I'm actually initializing Automapper within it... so of what use, then, is the dependency injection? Any clues? Here is the relevant code:

```cs
public class MyResolver : IValueResolver<Entity, Model, List<Model>>
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;


    public MyResolver(IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public MyResolver()
    { //If I don't initialize the mapper here, code won't run.
    }
    public List<Model> Resolve(Entity source, Model destination, List<Model> member, ResolutionContext context)
    {

        var list = source.Entities.Where(x => x.Gender == Gender.Female).ToList();
        var newList = new List<Model>();
        try
        {
            foreach (Entity e in list)
            {
                var m = _mapper.Map<Model>(e);
                newList.Add(m);
            }
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            var msg = ex.Message;
        }
        return newList;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any need to inject or initialize the mapper within the constructor of your `IValueResolver`. You can just use the mapper accessible via the `ResolutionContext` as follows:

```cs
public class MyResolver : IValueResolver<Entity, Model, List<Model>>
{
    public List<Model> Resolve(Entity source, Model destination, List<Model> member, ResolutionContext context)
    {

        var list = source.Entities.Where(x => x.Gender == Gender.Female).ToList();
        var newList = new List<Model>();
        try
        {
            foreach (Entity e in list)
            {
                var m = context.Mapper.Map<Model>(e);
                newList.Add(m);
            }
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            var msg = ex.Message;
        }
        return newList;

    }
}
```

Comment: No need for that. `MapFrom(s => s.Entities.Where(x => x.Gender == Gender.Female))`.